# Suggest best way to do this approval workflow for share point form library

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, list

I have created the Info path form.

Once the new form created i need to send the email to users which the user selected  in the people picker field.

Is that possible to do this using Designer,or VS 2010.

Give some reference to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you want to run a Workflow on an Infopath from, possibly in a Forms Library. All this workflow does is to send an e-mail to people selected in an people picker (called contact selector in Infopath) field.

With Sharepoint Designer this is not as easily done, as the only way to get values from the underlying Infopath Form is to promote the fields. You can do this easily when you publish your form, as you are prompted there to promote the fields. The contact selector should either be promoted as a Sharepoint people picker or as a text field, I'm not sure - in either way you will receive a DOMAIN\USERNAME which you can use to e-mail your desired people.

Via Visual Studio you of course have more possibilities as you can just deserialize the XML from the Infopath form and can therefore get all values from the people picker to send an e-mail.

On how to retrieve values from an Infopath form you can look at this blog post: [How to retrieve InfoPath form data in a SharePoint workflow](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2009/02/how-to-retrieve-infopath-form-data-sharepoint-workflow/)

Answer (score 1):

In the Designer workflow:

```
Start APPROVAL process on CURRENT ITEM with THESE USERS
```

Click on *THESE USERS* and you can select *Workflow Lookup for a User*.

This allows you to select items entered by your form.